# Mediawiki include articles from external wiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have created my own wiki using mediawiki. Now I would like to know if it is possible to dynamically include articles from an external wiki.

For example, if my wiki does not contain an article about the topic "potato" and a user visits the page "mysite.com/wiki/potato", I would like to display on this page the potato-article of wikipedia.org (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato).

Is there a php solution (using the wikipedia-api) which can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches. Here are some rough ideas:

1. With the [ExternalData extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aExternal_Data) you can pull in data from Wikipedia's API.
2. The [Anysite extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAnysite) can put any other page in an iframe. You would probably want to use a [rendered](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki&action=render) version of the page, and somehow add back the CSS to make it look good.

Both of these don't solve the issue of someone landing on a page that does not exist yet. You can take a look at the code of the [Special404 extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSpecial404) for some ideas to get started. And if you start hacking something yourself you probably don't need the above extensions anymore.

But you should be aware of the problems with what you want to do. Are you sure you want to have *all* URLs that work on Wikipedia be valid URLs on your wiki? Are you okay with creating heaps of duplicate content?